# Restricting access to a given Google Group members

Tags: google-app-engine, google-groups

I’d like to check on my Google App Engine application whether an user belongs to a given Google Group.

I could check manually using their username, by copying the whole list of email addresses of that group, and comparing each individually, but that would require updating the list every time a user joins or leaves the group.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Is the group part of Google Apps managed domain, or a regular google groups hosted on groups.google.com?

Comment: It is a regular google group (hosted on groups.google.com)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API to currently access public google groups members. I would recommend starring this feature request http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=27.

Comment: Also take look at https://github.com/auzigog/google-groups-php-api which is an unofficial API for google groups that rely on screen scrapping. They don't currently support checking group membership but I believe this could be easily extended/ported to App Engine.

Comment: I foresee this as a FR for our User API for google apps managed domain, as people might want to restrict access to certain domain groups.

Answer (score 0):

No. As proppy suggested in the comment, certainly you can do something like screen scraping, but it's a very fragile way and not appropriate for important things like authentication.

There is also [a feature request about it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7033). Consider starring this issue.